# How case in SELECT clause can affect the resultset in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, select, case

I'm facing a strange behavior in SQL Server. I have a query how return 233 rows and it's fine.

The problem is if I add a condition in a CASE, well, she returns 48 rows. How is it possible ? CASE shouldn't change my results : it's a CASE in a SELECT clause and there is no WHERE on it.

See the query below. The part between *** ... *** is the condition who change the result of the entire query.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN dq.type_of_cover = 'ndd' AND ah.type_of_cover = 'ndaa' THEN ah.type_of_cover 
    ELSE dq.type_of_cover 
END AS type_of_cover,
CASE 
    WHEN (dq.type_of_cover = 'CCD' AND dq.result_code = 'CCP') THEN NULL --a.mntgex
    WHEN (ah.type_of_cover = 'ndaa' *** AND ah.date = GETDATE() ***) THEN ah.first_amount
    ELSE ISNULL(dq.first_amount, 0)
END AS problem,
dq.active
FROM (
    SELECT du.coddeb, du.coduti
    FROM cacheDebiteurConsolideByUtilisateur AS du
    WHERE du.coduti = 4102
) AS debi
INNER JOIN DecisionQueue AS dq ON dq.coddeb = debi.coddeb
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 type_of_cover,  MIN(date) AS date, first_amount, coddeb, codadh 
    FROM AtradiusCLHistory
    WHERE codadh = 1003
    AND dq.coddeb = coddeb
    GROUP BY type_of_cover, first_amount, coddeb, codadh
) AS ah
WHERE dq.codadh = 1003
AND dq.cancelled != 1
) AS test 
WHERE type_of_cover = 'ndaa' AND active = 1
```

So when I got **AND ah.date = GETDATE()** in the "problem" CASE, I have 48rows, when not, 233.

Comment: That is because getdate() returns the current datetime (not date) and unless you have rows that match exactly you will not get them returned. If ah.date is a date column you could cast getdate to a date. (btw, naming columns using reserved words is a bad idea, so it making the name so ambiguous you have no idea what it means)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Well, i tried to Cast GETDATE() but it change nothing. I still have 48 rows returning.

I dont get it, how a case in a select can affect the result like if he was a WHERE clause ?

I changed the column name, but still the same result :/

Comment: Simply put, a case expression will NOT filter the rows. Your query seems to be overly complicated. Simplifying your query would be a good place to start in debugging this.

Comment: I agree with you. But it does.

However i'll try to simplifying it. I know that the subqueries is useless and all (it's not mine, i'm trying to help a colleague)

Comment: It can't. That is not at all how sql works. There may be some other level of filtering that is causing it to behave that way but just the existence of a case expression will NOT change number of rows returned. It is impossible to help you any further unless you provide a LOT more details. sqlfiddle.com would be a good place to start.

Comment: I know it cant in fact. But I know what i'm seeying on SSMS too. I juste change this condition and the result set is affected, believe me.

I was thinking about sqlfiddle, but it's gonna take me long time :/

Maybe the Execution Plan will help me. I was just wondering if someone had the same problem.